# How to request a previously uploaded file | JavaScript FileReader

Tags: javascript, filereader

I'm working on a web app that allows users to edit images/videos. I want the user to be able to save their work, and resume it again at a later time.

Instead of copying over whatever file the user is editing into local storage, I'd like to do as most video editing programs and save a 'reference' to that file (ie: the system path), and reload it later.

If the file is deleted/moved the 'reference' will be broken, and I can handle the error in my app.

Problem is I can't find a way to do this reading through the [FileReader API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader). Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no API which would make that possible.